# set up context variable in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6, servlet-filters

I am having problem setting up tomcat context variable. 
I have tried:

1. in web.xml in root folder(note: it's not the one in conf folder) 
   I tried adding context-param, not work, this did not change anything, the context variable is still null

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>testname</param-name>
       <param-value>testvalue</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```
2. using servlet getServletContext.setAttribute("test","ok") to set variable, it does not work either, the variable just stay null all the time.
3. i have tried to add crossContext=true in server.xml (even though i only have one webapp), it does not work.

so any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: basically, i want change value of context variable and later one another servlet can use it

Comment: What's the functional requirement? Setting up a variable which is accessible by all web applications deployed on the very same Tomcat server?

Comment: yes, the variable will have to be accessed by other filters on same server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the context parameter to the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` of your webapp, not one "in root folder" wherever that is.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>testname</param-name>
    <param-value>testvalue</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You need to get it by [`ServletContext#getInitParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String testname = getServletContext().getInitParameter("testname");
System.out.println(testname); // testvalue
```

The `ServletContext#set/getAttribute()` sets/gets attributes in the application scope. They are not related to context parameters.

Comment: sorry, i should be more clear on that, this variable is accessed by others on same server within one application. currently, i only have one webapp on server.  in addition, i dont have access to run command on server(it's a shared hosting server), so environment variable might not be a good idea.

Comment: no wonder i always got null, because i used getServletContext().getAttribute("test"). I thought getInitParameter("test") is used only when <init-param> is specified in <servlet>, now i got it

Comment: Context attributes are not the same as context parameters. The servlet init parameters are only available by `ServletConfig` or the inherited `GenericServlet#getInitParameter()`. As to setting the value, do a guess... (hint: read javadoc).

Comment: To learn about what attributes are and how they are to be used, take some time to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading, which should be enlightening in general.